# how to display block div on hover a tag

Tags: css

how to open div tag on hover a tag

## Service is id of a tag

## Services is id of div tag

My Html Code is

```
<ul><li><a href="#" id="Service">Services</a></li></ul>

<div id="Services">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

and my css code is this

```
#Services
    {
        display: none;
    }

    #Service:hover + #Services
    {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: The + combinator is for sibling selectors, and `#Service` and `#Services` are not siblings... `#Service` is nested in a list, you would need to adjust your markup for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

`#Services` isn't a sibling of `#Service`, so the `+` selector won't match it.

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KX5f6/)** for modified markup which makes the two siblings. You will need to style it accordingly.

```
<ul><li><a href="#" id="Service">Services</a>
    <div id="Services">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `#services` as the siblings element of the `#service`. Then the code would work.

Such as this:

```
<div>
  <a href="" id="service">Hyperlink</a>
  <div id="services">Some text</div>
</div> <!-- or any other of the container element -->
```